# How to Handle a Kafka Record with a Class-Level @KafkaListener with no @KafkaHandler for the Record Value

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Normally, when we define a class-level `@KafkaListener` and method level `@KafkaHandler`s, we can define a default `@KafkaHandler` to handle unexpected payloads.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#class-level-kafkalistener

But, what should we do if we don't have a default method?

Comment: I asked and answered this question in response to a [comment on an old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59256214/multiple-implementations-of-kafka-message-java-generics/59256387#comment116582281_59256387).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With version 2.6 and later, you can configure a `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` to immediately send such messages to a dead letter topic, by examining the exception.

Here is a simple Spring Boot application that demonstrates the technique:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So59256214Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So59256214Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic1() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so59256214").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic2() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so59256214.DLT").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so59256214.DLT", topics = "so59256214.DLT")
    void listen(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> in) {
        System.out.println("dlt: " + in);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, Object> template) {
        return args -> {
            template.send("so59256214", 42);
            template.send("so59256214", 42.0);
            template.send("so59256214", "No handler for this");
        };
    }

    @Bean
    ErrorHandler eh(KafkaOperations<String, Object> template) {
        SeekToCurrentErrorHandler eh = new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(template));
        BackOff neverRetryOrBackOff = new FixedBackOff(0L, 0);
        BackOff normalBackOff = new FixedBackOff(2000L, 3);
        eh.setBackOffFunction((rec, ex) -> {
            if (ex.getMessage().contains("No method found for class")) {
                return neverRetryOrBackOff;
            }
            else {
                return normalBackOff;
            }
        });
        return eh;
    }

}

@Component
@KafkaListener(id = "so59256214", topics = "so59256214")
class Listener {

    @KafkaHandler
    void integerHandler(Integer in) {
        System.out.println("int: " + in);
    }

    @KafkaHandler
    void doubleHandler(Double in) {
        System.out.println("double: " + in);
    }

}
```

```
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
```

Result:

```
int: 42
double: 42.0
dlt: ConsumerRecord(topic = so59256214.DLT, ...
```